# Jssor Slider - full width Thumbnail navigator in full width slider container possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jssor

my apologies if this is covered elsewhere,

Within a responsive full width slider container I am using thumbnail navigator 03 with the scaling option set to false.

Is it possible to have a full i.e. 100% width thumbnail navigator (but with a fixed height) that doesn't scale within a responsive slider container?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution is,

Set $Scale option to false, and use a wrapper to wrap the thumbnail navigator

```
            $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable thumbnail navigator or not
                ...

                $Scale: false,                                  //Scales thumbnail navigator or not while slider scale
                ...
            }
```

html code:

```
    <div u="thumbwrapper" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100px; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="position: relative; left: 50%; width: 5000px; height: 100px; text-align: center; margin-left: -2500px;">
            <!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin Begin -->
            <div u="thumbnavigator" ...">
            </div>
            <!-- Thumbnail Navigator Skin End -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please see this demo http://www.jssor.com/testcase/thumbnail-with-no-scale-2.source.html